# Calculate complex impedance value from voltage in time domain waveform

Tags: impedance, physics, electrochemical

I have problem. I was doing an electrochemical impedance spectroscopy (EIS) test on my Randles cell.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faIOTR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The data from potensiostat's output is written in a .csv file.

If we plot the .csv, it will show the voltage amplitude in the time domain.

I am using this Ohm's law equation to find the impedance.

> Z(ω) = V(ω)/I(ω)

My questions:

1. Am I doing this the right way to find the impedance when I have voltage as time domain waveform data?
2. How can I calculate the impedance with the FFT to find the complex value of impedance? (Zreal and Zimaginary.)

Comment: Where is ground or 0 volts on your schematic? What are CE, WE and RE all about? Which impedance is your cell in your diagram? What voltage are you measuring? What is your excitation voltage and source impedance?

Comment: I guess that data is "impedance " between CE and RE. It is a "simple" first order system. Steady value will give you R+Rc. At start, R... then C.